# How to plot groups of line plots from multiple files

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, line-plot

I have two files one.txt and two.txt which contains two columns and three rows as

A.txt

```
A    B  C
1994 4  6
1996 8  10
1998 10 14
```

and B.txt as

```
A    B   C
1995 14  2
1997 18  5
1999 12  9
```

I want to create a two list by importing the value from each column of both files such that

```
list1 = [[1994, 1996, 1998], [1995,1997,1999]]
list2 =[[4,8,10] , [14, 18, 12]]
```

and then plot the figure using matplotlib in single figure from both list1 and list2 to compare the figure.

```
#To create a list of files inside directory I did this
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()

# list to store files
res = []
# Iterate directory
for file in os.listdir(cwd):
    # check only text files
    if file.endswith('.txt'):
        res.append(file)

#then to create a two list from each file i did this
nxyear = []
nxdata = []

myyear = []
mydata = []

for fin in res:
   print(fin)

   GNSS = fin[0:4]    # station name, e.g., UH01
   ts_enu = []
   ts_enu = pd.read_csv (fin, header=0, delim_whitespace=True)
   year = ts_enu.iloc[:,0]    # year
   dis = ts_enu.iloc[:,1]     # NS
   myyear = []
   mydata = []
   myyear.append(year)
   mydata.append(dis)

nxyear.append(myyear)
plt.plot(myyear,mydata)
plt.show()
```

But it's not working to get same output as I want. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Most of this code is completely unnecessary. See Option 4 of [Import multiple CSV files into pandas and concatenate into one DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21232849/7758804) with `files = Path(path).glob('*.txt')`

Comment: `df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, sep='\\s+', usecols=[0, 1]) for i, f in enumerate(files)), axis=1)` and `df.columns = ['y0', 'v0', 'y1', 'v1']` in this case.

Comment: And `for row in df.itertuples(): plt.plot([row.y0, row.y1], [row.v0, row.v1], marker='.')` to plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to plot each value A of all text files in a single plot.

However, I don't understand "to compare the figure". With what?

Your code is quite over-complicated. However, here is a working version based on your script. (For another version see below.)

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cwd = os.getcwd()

files = []

for file in os.listdir(cwd):
    if file.endswith('.txt'):
        files.append(file)

# collect years and values (unnecessary step, see script example below)
years = []
values = []

for file in files:

    df = pd.read_csv(file, header=0, delim_whitespace=True)

    # add years and values to a list
    # better use pd.concat, see script example below
    years.append(df["A"].tolist())
    values.append(df["B"].tolist())

plt.plot(years, values, "o")  # <-- add "o" for circle marker
plt.show()
```

If you want to clean up your code, here is a suggestion using `Path` and Pandas, and avoiding using unnecessary lists:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pathlib import Path

# retrieve all text files from the working directory
files = Path.cwd().glob("*.txt")

# load all dataframes
dataframes = (pd.read_csv(file, header=0, delim_whitespace=True) for file in files)

# concat dataframes to one dataframe
data = pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index=True)

# plot figure
plt.plot(data["A"], data["B"], "o")
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]